# Rails can't find the module, if config.cache_classes = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I have a gem which is mounted as engine in my rails app via `routes.rb` & `Gemfile`. Here are the important pieces:

Apps' **Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'mysql2'


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "common_client", path: "../common-client"
```

App's **routes.rb**

```
mount CommonClient::Engine => "", :as => 'shared'
```

gem's **routes.rb**

```
get '/register' => 'session#new_registration'
```

gems's **SessionController**

```
require 'common_client/session_controller_base'

class SessionController < ApplicationController

  include CommonClient::SessionControllerBase
end
```

gems's **SessionControllerBase**

```
module CommonClient

  module SessionControllerBase

  def new_registration
      #some code goes here
  end
end
```

This works just fine in development & rails is able to find `CommonClient::SessionController` & execute `new_registration` action whenever visitor hits `/register` route. But in Production, rails is unable to find `CommonClient::SessionController` & generates the following error:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.9 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-12-09 03:27:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-12-09 03:27:29] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-10-12) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-12-09 03:27:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4248 port=3000
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-09 03:28:17 +0530
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Redirected to localhost:3000/register
Filter chain halted as :check_credentials rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 267ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-09 03:28:18 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant CommonClient::SessionController):
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4296103602150594596__call__1936882885794917979__callbacks'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundles/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


^C[2012-12-09 03:42:57] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2012-12-09 03:42:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
```

Now,
here is the interesting part. These errors goes away in production & app works just fine when I disable code caching in `production.rb`. by setting

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

All this makes me wonder,

1. why rails can `CommonClient::SessionController` in development env but not in production env?
2. How does setting `config.cache_classes = false` makes it work in production? And rails can find `CommonClient::SessionController` which it was not able to do earlier
3. What I need to do when so that rails finds `CommonClient::SessionController` other than ugly hack of disabling code cache & reloading all code on each request?

Lastly, I have tried to explain as best I could but still something is not clear or more information is required. Please leave a comment. Thanks

Comment: maybe you have to specify somewhere to load the module? i dont know where exactly

Comment: you would happen to have this in a rails app that's on github, or a dummy app that's on github?

Comment: config.cache_classes = true ensures your application doesn't recompile between code changes, as it's not required in prod env.  Clearing your cache might fix this.

Comment: Have you used ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) hooks?

Comment: The common_client/session_controller_base.rb file is in lib folder? Try use require_dependency "common_client/session_controller_base" on SessionController instead require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try update routes.rb like:

```
require 'common_client'
mount CommonClient::Engine => '/shared'
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this has to do with load order. In development mode (when cache_classes is false), Rails will load up all your unloadable classes on every request. This happens *after* the rest of the framework has been initialized.

By comparison, in production mode, everything is loaded up in one shot, so it's possible that your CommonClient is being loaded before some other piece of the Rails stack, and then getting hidden by the Rails load. Valery's suggestion about the ActiveSupport hooks is a good one - what does the CommonClient railtie look like? You may be able to modify your gem's railtie to load your controllers after ActionController loads, which should provide behavior much more similar to Rails' development-mode load behavior.