# Application not working when 'config.cache_classes = true'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `Rails 3.2.15` application.

When I set (`config/environments/production.rb`)

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

my application is not getting started.

When I set it to:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

everything works just fine. (But obviously causes performance degradations.)

Any one please suggest to run my application in 'config.cache_classes = true' mode or improve my application performance.

Comment: Is there any error in the logs ?

Comment: uninitialized constant Specialties (NameError)
  /var/sample/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782923/rails-cant-find-the-module-if-config-cache-classes-true Last post could be helpful to you.

Comment: Nope.. :( it not helps